# Send eth programmatically php

Tags: php, laravel, coinbase-api, coinbase-php

I use https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-php with laravel to send Eth from my wallet to wallet on other service.

I use this method: `$client->createAccountTransaction($account, $transaction);`

In this way:

```
$transaction = Transaction::send([
    'to' => new EthrereumAddress($destination_address),
    'amount'           => new Money($amount, $currency),
    'description'      => $description,
    //'fee'              => '0.0001' // only required for transactions under BTC0.0001
]);
$this->client->createAccountTransaction($account, $transaction);
```

But when I try to do this, I get this error:

> The Coinbase API only accepts transactions to an account, email, or bitcoin address

Can someone tell me how to send eth or what is wrong ?

Comment: The message seems to originate from [this line](https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-php/blob/0703d1827f786ba208de410b6b887037e1af9c4e/src/Mapper.php#L125). It checks that `to` is of type `Email`, `BitcoinAddress` or `Account`. Your `EthrereumAddress` (is that a typo?) might not derive from any of those.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in the latest 2.8.0 version.

https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-php/releases/tag/2.8.0

You should use right `$account` for each cryptocurrency, but not just the `$client->getPrimaryAccount();`

For example:

```
$account = Account::reference('YOUR_ETH_ACCOUNT_ID');
```